# having condition with if else conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to find all the film categories in which there are between 55 and 65 films. Return the names of these
categories and the number of films per category, sorted by the number of films. If there are no categories
between 55 and 65, return the highest available counts.

```
SELECT 
    c.name,
    fc.category_id,
    COUNT(fc.category_id) as ccc
FROM
    film_category fc
JOIN category as c on
    c.category_id = fc.category_id
GROUP BY
    fc.category_id
HAVING CASE 
    WHEN ccc BETWEEN 55 AND 65 THEN ccc
    WHEN ccc NOT BETWEEN 55 AND 65 THEN ccc LIMIT 3 //or we can get only the largest one
  --ELSE ccc NOT BETWEEN 55 AND 65  // or we can do it with else?
END
ORDER BY
    ccc DESC;
```

so how to do it in the best efficient way?

of course, the result of my query is not fully true because I get all the rows even not between 55 and 65

and this is my result without limit 3

```
+-------------+-------------+-----+
| name        | category_id | ccc |
+-------------+-------------+-----+
| Sports      |          15 |  74 |
| Foreign     |           9 |  73 |
| Family      |           8 |  69 |
| Documentary |           6 |  68 |
| Animation   |           2 |  66 |
| Action      |           1 |  64 |
| New         |          13 |  63 |
| Drama       |           7 |  62 |
| Sci-Fi      |          14 |  61 |
| Games       |          10 |  61 |
| Children    |           3 |  60 |
| Comedy      |           5 |  58 |
| Classics    |           4 |  57 |
| Travel      |          16 |  57 |
| Horror      |          11 |  56 |
| Music       |          12 |  51 |
+-------------+-------------+-----+
16 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

sample data of category table:

```
mysql> select * from category;
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
| category_id | name        | last_update         |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
|           1 | Action      | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           2 | Animation   | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           3 | Children    | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           4 | Classics    | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           5 | Comedy      | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           6 | Documentary | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           7 | Drama       | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           8 | Family      | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|           9 | Foreign     | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|          10 | Games       | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|          11 | Horror      | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|          12 | Music       | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|          13 | New         | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|          14 | Sci-Fi      | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|          15 | Sports      | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
|          16 | Travel      | 2006-02-15 04:46:27 |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

sample data of film_category table:

```
mysql> select * from  film_category limit 10;
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| film_id | category_id | last_update         |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|       1 |           6 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       2 |          11 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       3 |           6 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       4 |          11 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       5 |           8 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       6 |           9 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       7 |           5 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       8 |          11 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|       9 |          11 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
|      10 |          15 | 2006-02-15 05:07:09 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: the rows should be shown are only 10 rows that the ccc column between 55 and 65 and the other rows lets say should  show if there are not ccc rows between 55 and 65

Comment: I feel like we're maybe missing a table here.  Can you show sample data for both tables in your question?

Comment: The simplest way (it seems) is UNION 2 queries - with `ccc BETWEEN 55 AND 65` without limitation and with `ccc NOT BETWEEN 55 AND 65` with `LIMIT 3`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is it clear now?

Comment: No, not clear. Sample data must be CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. And specify MySQL version.

Comment: sorry @Akina I didn't understand why do you want the CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, can you rephrase, please

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas the version is 5.7.29

Comment: *I didn't understand why do you want the CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts* This allows to re-create your table(s) and test our solution(s). You may create online fiddle instead and post the link.

Comment: @Akina I am testing my queries on sakila database and this is the link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html  .... contains the schema and the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for MySQL 8+

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT c.name,
                 fc.category_id,
                 COUNT(fc.category_id) as cnt
          FROM film_category fc
          JOIN category c ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
          GROUP BY fc.category_id ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT name, 
                 category_id,
                 cnt
          FROM cte1
          WHERE cnt BETWEEN @from AND @to
          ORDER BY cnt DESC )
SELECT name, 
       category_id,
       cnt
FROM cte2
UNION ALL
( SELECT name, 
         category_id,
         cnt
  FROM cte1
  WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM cte2 ) = 0
  ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 3 )
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

```sql
mysql> SET @from := 60;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @to := 65;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /* query skipped */
+----------+-------------+-----+
| name     | category_id | cnt |
+----------+-------------+-----+
| Action   |           1 |  64 |
| New      |          13 |  63 |
| Drama    |           7 |  62 |
| Games    |          10 |  61 |
| Sci-Fi   |          14 |  61 |
| Children |           3 |  60 |
+----------+-------------+-----+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @from := 35;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @to := 45;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> /* query skipped */
+---------+-------------+-----+
| name    | category_id | cnt |
+---------+-------------+-----+
| Sports  |          15 |  74 |
| Foreign |           9 |  73 |
| Family  |           8 |  69 |
+---------+-------------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

On version 5+ you may, of course, convert CTEs to subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try this query but I think it could be something like this, and it would help you to advance your query:

```
SELECT 
    c.name,
    fc.category_id,
    COUNT(fc.category_id) as ccc
FROM
    film_category fc
INNER JOIN category as c on
    c.category_id = fc.category_id
GROUP BY
    fc.category_id
HAVING ccc > 55 AND ccc < 65
```

Comment: I know this query, my problem is with adding cases to having condition, thank you by the way.